# Gaussians as Markov Kernels

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Let the one-step transition dynamics of a system be given as
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P}[X_{t+1} | X_t] = N(f_\theta(X_t), I)
\end{equation*}
that is the Normal with mean a function of $X_t$ paramterized by $\theta$. My question is what would be $$\mathbf{P}[X_{t+2} | X_t] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathbf{P}[X_{t+2} | X_{t+1}]\mathbf{P}[X_{t+1} | X_t]dX_{t+1}?$$

Is there a simple closed form solution for a general $f_\theta$? That is would $\mathbf{P}[X_{t+2} | X_t]$ be a Normal Distribution?  What if the one step transition is given as a linear function e.g,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P}[X_{t+1} | X_t] = N(AX_t+b, I) ?
\end{equation*}
What would the mean and variance be if it is a normal distribution?